# Action Script 3 loading images from remote domain

Tags: actionscript-3, vk, loading-image

I have an application that is running on portal VK com. I need to load images (.png) from their domain (which are players avatars basicly). What I get is `SecurityError: Error #2123`. It looks like in crossdomain.xml file on their domain there is no proper  tag.

I've done following things:

1. Set `allowSecurityDomain` to * in my swf
2. I'm passing `LoaderContext` to Loader::load method defined like this:

   ```
   var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
   var context.checkPolicyFile = true;
   loader.load(new URLRequest(img), context);
   ```

This is working on other portals (facebook, mojmir, odnoklassiniki, etc..) but not this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load images you can use the Image tag:

```
 <mx:Image source="http://...." autoload="true" />
```

You won't have to deal with cross domain policy.

In AScript you can use:

```
var img:Image = new Image();
img.autoLoad = true;
img.source = "http://someurl/img.png"
img.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void {
   //loaded
});
img.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
   //not loaded
});
```

Comment: hmm I need to do it from inside action acript 3 code not flex application